# absolute child covered by relative parent with overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

I have a Student searchable input box that generates a dropdown using angularJs directive.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchString" />
<span class="results-container" ng-show="showContainer">
    <span ng-if="results.length > 0" class="result-row" ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="assign(result)">
        {{result.Name}}
    </span>
</span>
```

As you can see here, the body of the pop up (relative, overflow: auto) is covering the results container (absolute).

[image]

If I remove the **overflow: auto** from the parent .. it will look like this which is what i want. But I do not want to remove the **overflow** because the dialog is generic with a max-height that will have to be scrollable.

[image]

I assume this is achievable because the native **select** is not covered by its parent with **overflow: auto** just fine. Like this:

[image]

Also, one of the possible solution that I cannot use is putting the results container outside the input container. I am writing this using angular directive and you can have multiple of these searchable inputs on other pages. Moving them outside would break everything. Any css expert help?

Comment: How about using `z-index` for the `select`?

Comment: @TheUknown I tried that, I dont think it's a z-index problem.

Comment: No I meant, use a higher `z-index` so it overlaps other elements and you dont need to change any other css. Does that work for you?

Comment: @TheUknown yes i tried that, it doesnt work. When you have an overflow on the parent it ignores all z-indexes on the children.. i think

Comment: I'm not sure if its that or its something to do with the position. Try setting the `position:relative` with `z-index` for the `select`

Comment: @TheUknown i don't want to set position: relative on the results-container cus then that would push everything below down. Although theres nothing below in this case.